# Populate asp labels from SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I wrote the code to query the database, but now do not know how to get the text into my two labels 'txtTitle' & 'txtBody'

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blcDocumentationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            // Create Command Object
            SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

            pnlNew.Visible = false;
            pnlView.Visible = true;

            try
            {
                // Open Connection
                thisConnection.Open();

                // Create SELECT statement with named parms
                nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DocumentTitle,DocumentBody FROM tblDocument WHERE DocumentID = @DocumentID"; 

                // Add parms to Command parms collection
                nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentID", GridView1.SelectedValue);

                // Execute query statement
                nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Populate Labels
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
                lblTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                lblBody.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }

            finally
            {
                // Close Connection
                thisConnection.Close();
            }
        }

<asp:Panel ID="pnlView" runat="server" Visible="False" CssClass="pnlView">
                <h1 style="background-color: #CCE6FF">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h1>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></p>
                <p style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit This Document" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />&nbsp;or
                    cancel</p>
            </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you have a table filled with documents IDs (I'm assuming you already bound this correctly in some other part of your code)

You used the SelectedIndexChanged event correctly, but why are you executing another query inside?  If executing the query is intentional, why are you binding your labels to old data?  row.cells[].value holds old information, not the information you re-queried.  If you want the information you re-queried for, get that info directly from the result set.  Also, that result set will return nothing unless you change nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); to nonqueryCommand.ExecuteDataSet();

Comment: ExecuteDataSet() gives me an error. I am asking how to get the data from the query into the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating what User:rkw mentioned above. ExecuteNonQuery will not get any data back from the database. You need to use either DataReader  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx ) or use the ExecuteDataset and put the information into a DataSet and then read from it. When you say ExecuteNonQuery you are basically telling the SQL server to execute commands but not expecting any data back from the SQL Server.

Comment: SqlDataReader Document = getDocument.ExecuteReader();
lblTitle.Text = Document.GetValue(string);

Am i on the right track?